# What would the apparent size of the four stars in the Capella system be from the L1 point between the first pair?

Tags: lagrange-point

Capella is a system with four stars in two binary pairs ([source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capella)). If an observer were located at the L1 LaGrange point between the larger pair, how many degrees of the sky would each of the stars - both the first and second pairs - occupy?